# Rails bundler is not finding correct Ruby version in OSX Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, macos-catalina

I've recently upgraded to OSX Catalina and when I try to do

> bundle install

on the Rails project, I get an error:

> Cannot bundle the project, current system is on Ruby 2.6.3 and gemfile
>   specified Ruby 2.4.2.

What's bizarre is that the Catalina system is a fresh install and I used rbenv to do a single install of Ruby version 2.4.2.  In fact, if I run

> ruby -v

It comes back with ruby version 2.4.2 as the only ruby version installed (and the default).

I'm totally stumped, has anyone else seen this behaviour or have any idea of how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you run `env` and post the results? Be sure and delete any "secret" key values like `AWS_SECRET...` if you have any.

Comment: @Beartech - Thanks, I actually didn't think of that and good to know next time I get unpredictable environmental results!  I finally figured it out and posted the answer below, I still found it odd.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved this, although I'm a little mystified as to the cause/solution.

Basically, I uninstalled the bundler gem and installed the one the project had in it's Gemfile (1.16.2)

For whatever reason, I'm not sure how bundler got installed on the fresh machine, I suspect maybe through RVM or Rbenv, but with that version of bundler it was somehow assuming that I had Ruby 2.6.3 installed, even though it didn't appear as a version on my machine.